# Android: Implement admob on surfaceview

Tags: android, android-activity, integration, admob, surfaceview

I have an activity in form of a small game which uses SurfaceView. Below are the code snippets.. I am confused how to implement admob on surfaceview. Please suggest.

```
public class DroidzActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = DroidzActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // set our MainGamePanel as the View
        setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
        Log.d(TAG, "View added");
    }
}

public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
}
```

**Answer**

> Updated the code as below

```
public class DroidzActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String TAG = DroidzActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String MY_AD_UNIT_ID = "XYZ";
    private AdView adView;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // set our MainGamePanel as the View
        //setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        adView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(new MainGamePanel(this));
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        setContentView(layout);

        Log.d(TAG, "View added");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
        if (adView != null) {
              adView.destroy();
            }       
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the root view for DroidzActivity be a LinearLayout containging an AdView and MainGamePanel.

Comment: Thansk for the hint William, updated the question with answer. Please review!

Comment: Personally I would have defined the layout in XML but you can code it if you want.